# ReactJS confusing 'JS code as text' and real JS code: Add javascript code as text in ReactJS div

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react JS component, in which I want to enter some sample JS code as text inside the div.

Code looks something of this sort

```
render: function() {
return ( 
   <div id="sample_code_text">
       <p>
         if( 1==1 ) {
                              console.log(50) ;
         }
       </p>
    </div>
)};
```

I get an error at the console.log(50);

```
 Uncaught Error: Parse Error: Line 37: Unexpected token ;
```

React's div confuses 'code as text' as JS code. How do I fix this?

Comment: What about excaping the curly brackets? `if (1 == 1) \\{`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ES6 template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings) like so,

```
render: function() {
    var a = 10;
    return ( 
        <div id="sample_code_text">
            <p>
                {`
                    if (1 == 1) {
                       console.log(10);
                    }
                `}
            </p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/69z2wepo/17188/)

or use workaround solutions with `{ '{' }`, [because now there is no solution to easy escape `{}`](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1545)

```
render: function() {
    var a = 10;
    return ( 
        <div id="sample_code_text">
            <p>
                if (1 == 1) { '{' }
                   console.log(10);
                { '}' }
            </p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/69z2wepo/17187/)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is suggested by @dev-null.
Try this:

```
    <p>
      if( 1==1 ) {'{'}
        console.log(50) ;
      {'}'}
    </p>
```

Comment: Funny way to <s>escape</s> :-O

Comment: tried `\{` but in JSX (javascript) this does not produce any result in JSFiddle. `\\{` also.

Comment: I know the problem with `\{` is that - at least for strings - the escape character will be used to escape the bracket and will therefore be removed before it get send to the interpreter, hence the double escape: `'\{' === '{'`

Comment: Double escape did not work for me in JSFiddle. How would you put inside the complete code?

Comment: I don't think its possible. I have never worked with React and have no idea how their compiler works. I'm just stating how things would behave in JavaScript :-)

Comment: I see. Then my 'funny way' is still the correct way. ;) JSX is more or less HTML inside javascript. Escaping works differently in JSX than in javascript or HTML.